# Cannot read property 'name' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my problem is that sometimes `data.content[i].location.name` returns an error saying cannot read property 'name' of null.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
    classes.push({
       "id":data.post[i].id,
       "location":data.content[i].location.name,
       "type":data.content[i].type
   });
}
```

How can i fix this issue? I need data.content[i].location.name if it is not null.

Comment: is `name` or `location` null in these cases?

Comment: what do you mean by "fix"? fixing it can either be preventing the object from ever being null or it could mean checking if the object exists before trying to access the name property

Comment: are you passing that information to "data"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Test for the property using [.hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to prevent getting the error

```
for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
 classes.push({
   "id":data.post[i].id,
   "location": data.content[i].location.hasOwnProperty‎("name") ?  data.content[i].location.name : "",
   "type":data.content[i].type
 });
}
```

Comment: return an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of null ` error :/

Comment: then perform the same test testing for `location` on `content[i]`

Comment: oh, i see... `location` is null :S

Comment: Right, if you read that error message carefully, it all makes sense. :p it's saying `null` doesn't have a `hasOwnProperty` method.

Answer (score 6):

Just do a check if `data.content[i].location.name != null` before doing your push

If you want something special to happen in the case where it is `null` you can do that in the `else`.

Or as you've indicated sometimes `location` is `null`, so check that too the same way.